# Nested Maps and Collections in Neo4j 2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I understand that node and relationship properties are limited to primitive types or arrays of primitive types. The "Maps" section of the [Neo4j 2.1 Reference Card](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.1/) mentions that:

> {name:'Alice', age:38,
> address:{city:'London', residential:true}}
>
> Literal maps are declared in curly braces much like property maps. Nested maps and collections are supported.

Of course something like:

```
CREATE (alice {name:'Alice', age:38, address:{city:'London', residential:true}})
```

throws an exception:

```
Error: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidType
```

In what context does Neo4j support nested maps and collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edited)

The reference card is a bit too subtle. The most important word is "literal". In other words, you can only use arbitrarily nested maps and arrays in literals, but you cannot store such things in a node or relationship.

For example, this works:

```
WITH {name:'Alice', age:38, address:[{city:'London', residential:true}, {city: 'Paris', residential: false} ]} AS x
RETURN x;
```

But this fails:

```
CREATE (x {name:'Alice', age:38, address:[{city:'London', residential:true}, {city: 'Paris', residential: false} ]})
RETURN x;
```

Comment: so how to store them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this by converting nested maps to json string. Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45398934/4147185)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a trick You can do to put a map of properties in the node like this

```
CREATE (x {
    `properties.name`: 'Alice', `properties.city`: 'London', `properties.residential`: true }
  )
```

Then in Your entity use the @CompositeProperty:

```
@CompositeProperty(converter = PropertiesToMapConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
```

and a converter that will convert needed types to those stored at graph DB.