# Neo4j - Nested Collection By Using UNWIND and MERGE With Error: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this kind of collection:

```
datas = {name:'Mahsa', address:[{city:'Berlin', residential:true}, {city: 'Paris', residential: false} ]}

 UNWIND { datas } AS data
 MERGE (p:Person { name : '" + data.name + "'  } ) ON CREATE SET p.address=" + data.address+ "
```

I got this error: **"Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof"**

I have read this link: [Nested Maps and Collections in Neo4j 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750016/nested-maps-and-collections-in-neo4j-2)

My question is: What can I do while I can not remove "x" from :
(x {name:'Alice', age:38, address:[{city:'London', residential:true}, {city: 'Paris', residential: false} ]})

because I am unwinding it instead of simple WITH.

and I read also: [Nested Map With Create or Merge Statement](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/142cqvjx9d/nested-maps)

> Nested maps are supported as constructs in cypher and expression
>   results, return values but not in the underlying Neo4j storage.

Is it possible that Neo4j accept nested collection for storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Property values can not be nested](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-node-properties.html#rest-api-property-values-can-not-be-nested). This means, for example, that an array property can only contain primitive values (of the same type).

You may want to consider having separate `Address` nodes related to each `Person`.

Comment: so you think the only way is separated nested properties? Because in one of links that i shared you mentioned to remove "x" as a literal from the begining of collection.

Comment: No, I am recommending you consider changing your data model so that there are `Address` nodes as well as `Person` nodes, and to have each `Person` node related to one or more `Address` nodes.