# How does one store group of nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are building a graph of artists / music / films and the interconnection between them.

We figured out that there can be possibly 2 types of data relationship groups, Simple and Compound.

**1) Example of Simple Data**

```
(Bob Marley)-[music:composer:compositions]->(Natural Mystic)
```

**2) Example of Compound Data**

```
(Bob Marley)-[award:award_nominee:award_nominations]->(*MANY*) 

award:award_nomination:award->Grammy Award for Best Music Film
award:award_nomination:ceremony->44th Annual Grammy Awards
award:award_nomination:nominated_for->Rebel Music - The Bob Marley Story
award:award_nomination:year->2001

award:award_nomination:award->Grammy Award for Best Music Film
award:award_nomination:ceremony->45th Annual Grammy Awards
award:award_nomination:nominated_for->Rebel Music - The Bob Marley Story II
award:award_nomination:year->2002
```

and many more like that

**I tried various ways to get this sorted**

1. A complete hierarchy etc. but the flowchart gets too messy and there
   is no way i can find out which award corresponds to which year for
   example.
2. Making a new node called "nominations" and storing the name value pairs to it, but in this case how do i store the information when it comes to a node like
   (grammy)-[some relation]->Bob marley? store it again as a node? that would be duplication of data.
3. Store entire 3 tier hierarchies as relationships. Fail because neo4j does not allow 3 relationships
4. neo4j  [Linked lists](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-linked-lists.html), but will this help? and is it the right thing to do
5. Neo4j ref card says that it allows nested properties for node but that appears to be a hoax. I tried the query, FAIL

   {name: "Alice", age: 38,
    address: {city: 'London', residential: true}}
   Literal maps are declared in curly braces much like property maps. Nested maps and collections are supported.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it's really broad and opinion-soliciting. That said: I have no idea what you're referring to in point #3 - Neo4j absolutely allows for 3 (or more) relationships between nodes. And point #5 - you misunderstood literal maps and the reference card. You cannot store nested content. Literal maps are for constructing content within your query - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25754628/272109) which explains better.

Comment: I think in #3 the OP is referring to having multiple relationship names on a single edge - similar to having multiple labels on a single node.

Comment: Tim is right on this one and also on the answer, looks like many others did not even get the question. Negative votes for what? for the question being to complex for a pea sized brain? Thanks a lot Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing traditional RDB hierarchical thinking - you need to change that. Graphs allow you to flatten out the hierarchy and make direct associations between related nodes for groups of related information.

I've created a set of nodes and relationships I think will give you the structure you're looking for and be extensible to your other scenarios. Plug the following commands into a neo4j db and see what you think:

```
// Create the nodes of the graph
CREATE (award:Award {name: "Grammy Award for Best Music Film"})
CREATE (date:AwardDate {year: 2001})

CREATE (film:Film {name: "Rebel Music - The Bob Marley Story"})
CREATE (event:Event {name: "44th Annual Grammy Awards", year: date.year})
CREATE (composition:Composition {name: "Natural Mystic"})
CREATE (composer:Composer {name: "Bob Marley"})

// Create the relationships between the graph nodes
MERGE (composer)-[:COMPOSITION]->(composition)
MERGE (composition)-[:SOUNDTRACK]->(film)

MERGE (event)-[:AWARD]->(award)
MERGE (event)-[:DATE]->(date)
MERGE (film)-[:DATE]->(date)
MERGE (composer)-[:DATE]->(date)
MERGE (composition)-[:DATE]->(date)

MERGE (film)-[:NOMINATED {year: date.year}]->(award)
MERGE (composer)-[:NOMINATED {year: date.year}]->(award)
MERGE (composition)-[:NOMINATED {year: date.year}]->(award)

MERGE (film)-[:EVENT]->(event)
MERGE (composer)-[:EVENT]->(event)
MERGE (composition)-[:EVENT]->(event)
```

Also, for any decent sized collection of nodes you'll need indexes on these labels.